# Python Gym "env.render()" doesn't show anything while other print()s work

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, render, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am running a cartpole tutorial on jupyter notebook, and it does every thing I want except rendering. It doesn't show the cartpole, but it is running and shows observations and there are no errors. How can I fix this?
[image: Observations printed, no rendering]

I expect this image
[image: Cartpole in gym]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors